# Save local file to MS teams

Tags: office365, ms-office, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a case where client requested the following requirement, when a user creates a new document on PC and tried to save that, it shows options to save on onedrive, SharePoint etc. But we want to share it directly to a Teams of which user is a part of.

So is there any way we can lists all the Team of logged-in users under Teams section similar to SharePoint sites option.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Answer (score 1):

Teams simply uses SharePoint behind the scenes for the "Files" tab, so the "SharePoint" option should actually help them get to what they need. Just remember that each "Channel" in Teams becomes a Folder in the SharePoint site

Comment: The approach you suggested will require extra effort each time a new channel or a Team is created. I want that to be by default for users.

Comment: You cannot do that, like Hilton said, Teams is not a location, it's just a hub that display SharePoint structure. Nothing is save in Teams